# How to write name 'Jonas' to force /j/ sound?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, translation, names, transliteration

In Poland and many European countries Jonas is a popular name, spelled slightly differently in each language (*Jonasz, Jonàs, Jonáš, Joonas*). In most of Europe and Africa it is pronounced with initial /j/ sound (as in **y**es). But native English speakers use /d͡ʒ/ (**j**oy). Polish people named *Jonasz* hate it when their name is pronounced this way, as it should be /j/.

How can I write this name to be read with the right sound? I think there are few obvious options:

1. Spell it *Yonas*. Is pronounced correctly, but looks a bit weird.
2. Spell it *Ionas*. Similar to 1.
3. Spell it *Jonas* and correct everyone who dares to pronounce it with /d͡ʒ/.
4. Write it in Russian alphabet as Йонаш or Ёнаш (would be pronounced correctly by Russians). No one will know how to read it, so they will *have to ask* for correct pronunciation. Disadvantages include being called a Russian spy and missing the point of even writing the name if no one can read it.

Is there a clever solution I haven't thought of? If not, which options looks best to native English speakers?

Comment: I wonder how it would be pronounced in France

Comment: @ChrisH [/ʒɔ.nɑ/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jonas#French), with /ʒ/ as in plea*s*ure

Comment: That was my thought too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing but *Yonas* will work here. English speakers will never know to pronounce the letter J any other way than like in *judge* otherwise. No native words use that spelling for IPA /j/.

Comment: I reckon most native speakers would expect the name *Jan* to have /j/  when applied to a man. Having known two people with *Jonas* as a surname, but pronounced both wrong initially: the first was indeed /j/ but the second was /d͡ʒ/. Both were English themselves. In other words you can't win

Comment: @ChrisH The only Jonas that comes to mind is the biblical one who travelled in whales.  You can't expect native speakers seeing an English word to imagine it isn't one.

Comment: @ChrisH Are you saying that it *is* possible *some* English people will pronounce Jonas with /j/?

Comment: @FranzWexler only if they've been corrected in the past. As tchrist says, they can't be expected to know at first (and as there are people called Jonas who use /d͡ʒ/ for their own names, there's no hope)

Comment: @ChrisH Johan, too, and it's variants. Although I'm never sure about Johannesburg...

Comment: @tchrist I take it you don't watch the Disney Channel? The Jonas brothers were my first exposure to the name, the guy in the whale being Jonah. And yes, they do use /d͡ʒ/.